# F12/"Go to definition" points to temp class file for a reference dll in VS2013 in win application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am working on migrating a windows application from Vs2008 to VS2013.I have a solution containing 5 projects(lets say P1,P2,P3,P4,P5). And I have another solution which contains only one project(lets say XYZ).All projects in first solution references the project in second solution. After adding  XYZ project dll in reference folders of 1,P2....and when click(F12/"Go to definition") on any method of XYZ it redirects me to a class file in temp folder. I know that if we add reference through "projects" option then we wont get this error. But here XYZ project is in different solution and I am supposed to add dll by browsing it. Any solution for issue?
Note: framework versions of all the projects are same.

Comment: If the IDE does not have access to source code, like it won't when you reference an external assembly, then all it can do is show you the declaration decompiled from the metadata of the assembly.  Probably what you meant with "class file in temp folder".  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: I didn't understand what is the issue. Can you clarify?

Comment: add references by project not by dlls then do a clean and build.

Comment: @HansPassant.Sorry , its my mistake. I was completely messed in my work and didn't think twice before posting the query. I realized that its a feature after posting the question. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @bruno.almeida: Please don't bother. Not a valid question. Thanks

Comment: @DanielB: Thanks for reply.